# ClojureScript format string with goog.string.format doesn't substitute

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, google-closure-library

I'm trying to format a color in hex for use in HTML, running ClojureScript in the browser.

Here's my "format" function.

```
(defn gen-format [& args] (apply gstring/format args) )
```

in a "strings" namespace where I've required the goog.string library with :

```
(:require [goog.string :as gstring] [goog.string.format :as gformat])
```

But when I try to call it from javascript :

```
document.write(mypackage.strings.gen_format("#%x%x%x",0,0,0));
```

it just returns `#%x%x%x`

It's not crashing. But the goog format function doesn't seem to be substituting the values in. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does `%x` do?

Looking at [format source sorce](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_string_stringformat.js.source.html#line39), it only supports `s`, `f`, `d`, `i` and `u`:

```
var formatRe = /%([0\-\ \+]*)(\d+)?(\.(\d+))?([%sfdiu])/g;
```

This seems to be working well for me:

```
mypackage.strings.gen_format("#%d%d%d", 0, 0, 0)
```

---

**UPDATE**: If you need to render a string with color, how about these:

```
(defn hex-color [& args]
  (apply str "#" (map #(.toString % 16) args))

(defn hex-color [r g b]
  (str "#" (.toString r 16) (.toString g 16) (.toString b 16))
```

Comment: %x is meant to be hexadecimal. It works with the Clojure version of string formatting. Maybe it's not supported in Javascript.  :-(

Comment: In this case I guess it's something that Java supports (mind you, it's pretty rich), but Google Closure does not. See http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-324.

Comment: This is not a real answer... The original problem still persists.